# capturing raw syslog messages with tcpdump

Tags: syslog

i am currently collecting logs from a cloud platform which i would like to keep anonymous.  while trying to create a custom parser for the syslogs that i am collecting i am trying to capture the raw syslog by using tcpdump.exe for windows.  the syntax that i am using to capture the raw syslog messages are: tcpdump.exe -s 0 -A udp port 514

the issue that i am having is that at the beginning of each syslog message it starts with:

..s....@._<133>

and ends with:

E..T..@.@..C#.?O

does anyone know what that means and/or how i can capture the raw syslog messages with tcpdump without the beginning and ending garbage?

Comment: has anyone else came across this?